# How to covert a docker image that terminates into a continuous service

Tags: docker

I have a task that I want to perform continuously (or to be more specific, on a schedule).
I have found a docker image, which implements performing the task once. Something like `docker run image_name thing_to_do`, which terminates once the job is done.

I want to build a new docker image, which repeatedly invokes the other image, telling it what to do.

I can probably inherit from the existing image, reverse engineer its entry points and use my own entry point. However, my intuition is that it should also be possible to use the existing implementation as-is, e.g. invoking the entrypoint of the image I inherited from. My search terms yielded nothing useful so far.

EDIT: Clarifying that the ideal deliverable is one image. Not an image + external setup and scripts that invoke it.

Comment: How about you use cron to run your docker image on schedule?

Comment: This forfeits the convenience of docker. It will work on my dev computer, but requires setup instructions for anyone else to use it.

Comment: I feel where you're coming from man but nothing's really stopping us from putting cron inside the container, right? Or maybe setup something with "processing" container + message broker.

Comment: If you can start another container, you can use that other container to pretty trivially root the whole host (the other container can run as root and bind-mount any part of the host filesystem).  I'd look for another approach.

Comment: @Chris, I updated my answer. May be this can help you.